# Частично не переведена страница с ошибкой 404

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Например: [ссылка на удалённый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458972/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

> Here are some similar questions that might be relevant:

---

> Try a Поиск в Google

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Перевести сообщение на странице Ошибки 404](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/249)

Comment: @NickVolynkin может разработчиков надо пинать с некоторой периодичностью (повышать приоритет задачи таким образом)? Это я про `статус-отложено`.

Comment: @alexolut Николас обещал, что завтра починят.

Comment: @NickVolynkin поставлю напоминалку :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В базе строк для локализации этого нет. Оставил запрос на то, чтобы передать задачу разработчикам.

Перевод:

> Вот некоторые вопросы, которые могут оказаться полезными:

Тут есть вторая часть фразы, поправил букву на строчную.

> Попробуйте [поиск в Google](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265825?key=2221702de28862703c55da48b9642eb1)